# Datasheets do not mention and explain enough about current

Tags: arduino, current, l298

I'm trying to build my first IoT project.

I'm using an L298 motor drive, an MCU-6050 6 axis gyroscope and accelerometer and an Arduino Due.

When going through their datasheets, most of the tables and information is about voltage or temperature. They barely mention details of how much current can be driven into a pin without damaging the pins.

What am I missing? Is current really not that important in lower voltages or I don't know how to read datasheets or maybe you have to calculate it?

The datasheets are:

[L298](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf)

[MCU-6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf)

Comment: The L298 shows Iih  and Iil on page 3/13. As you can see, they are microamps max so almost anything can supply enough current for them. For digital input pins that's usually the case. The other datasheet doesn't even seem to bother, as far as I can see. Presumably the input currents are even lower.

Comment: normally you do not worry about current in logic inputs or outputs ... just supply the correct voltage levels ... the only time you would worry about current is if you connect multiple inputs to one output

Comment: If you don't do anything wrong, there would be no error and no fried pins. But it's impossible to know if there is a wrong connection or something else, because the only thing that you described is what modules you will use, you didn't provided a schematic showing how will you connect them. Rule of thumb: make sure that L298 and the motors connected to it aren't supplied by Arduino.

Comment: @BrianDrummond those two values are only for the 4 input pins. I wanted to know the maximum current for the Vs and the Vss

Comment: @mguima I didn't say anything went wrong. I'm trying to understand the datasheets so I can prevent anything from frying. also, should I still not supply the motors with the arduino if they draw almost 4mA at 3V each?

Comment: **A motor that draws only 4mA @ 3V?** Sorry: it's impossible. Maybe nanomotors, with the size of half than a sesame seed... are you using nanotechnology? Even a tiny motor, one of those used in cell phones' vibracall, needs a minimum current the order of 90-100mA. I have no doubt that there is a mistake. Anyways, remember that Arduino output is at 5V, and your motor is 3V. But a 3V motor can fry an Arduino output, too. Of course, you don't need to trust me.